# Regarding $\displaystyle a_n=A_n + B_n \sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_j a_{n-j}$, an infinite system of non-linear algebraic equations

Tags: sequences-and-series, nonlinear-system

Solving a PDE, I ran into an infinite system of equations of the form

$$a_n=A_n + B_n \sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_j a_{n-j}, \qquad n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

where $A_n$ and $B_n$ and known coefficients while the $a_n$'s are the unknowns.

I wonder if

- Conditions may be set to ensure that at least a solution $\{a_n\}$ exists?

and

- How to compute it?

In the literature for linear systems I couldn't find any hint for this type of equations. Thank you for any suggestion.
Dario

Comment: That sum is a discrete convolution of $a$ with itself, so you might want to look for things about such convolutions. That also suggests the $a_n$ are the coefficients of a Fourier expansion, and the original PDE had a quadratic nonlinearity, yes?

Comment: Absolutely correct, it comes from a Fourier expansion of a PDE with a quadratic nonlinearity. The starting point is the Domenicali's equation $\partial_t u -\partial_{xx}u=\zeta j(t)^2$ with $j(t)=\beta (u(0,t)-u(1,t))$ and with BCs $\partial_x u(0,t)=-q(t)+\zeta j(t) u(0,t)$, $u(1,t)=u_0$ ($\zeta$ and $\beta$ are two constants).